# Anchor Events -- What, Why, How?

Tags: anchor, anchor-client

https://book.anchor-lang.com/ has no article on these yet, but I see many programs using them.

What is the problem that they are solving? What are the common code patterns and best practices for implementing and consuming events?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**What**: log messages (anything you would do with `msg!()`).  But they are not human readable as they are base64 encoded.

**Why**: `msg!()` with string formatting is relatively expensive for compute units

**How**: [example](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/tests/events/programs/events/src/lib.rs)

Comment: In [your example](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/27bb6956850477ecbb497dc6c8ff855d97501401/tests/events/tests/events.js#L36) how can you extract the tx signature from the program call `program.rpc.initialize();` that is wrapped in the Promise?

Answer (score 6):

They allow encoding of data into the transaction through the logs. They are more efficient that formatting a string (very expensive) and allow easy decoding through the anchor SDK

They can be used for:

- Notification
- Program activity tracking

Comment: Thanks, that sort of answers the "what / why?" 
When you say "tracking," do you mean realtime tracking? Pubsub? How is this accomplished? Can you point me to any illustrative examples on implementation and consumption?

Comment: I think it's websockets under the hood. But you can use Anchor's `Program.addEventListener` to subscribe to them on the client: https://coral-xyz.github.io/anchor/ts/classes/Program.html#addEventListener